# How to unauthorize/revoke LinkedIn token in my application

Tags: grails, oauth, token, linkedin-api

I have a grails application in which I want a user to grant me access to his/her LinkedIn account to get information and show it in different ways.

I was able to do the following:

1. Get the authorization code
2. Use that authorization code to get the Access Token
3. I store that Access Token together with the expiration date in my User entity.
4. Refresh that Access Token when the expiration date is within X days from today.

Now the issue I'm having is that I would like the user to revoke or invalidate that token so that someone else can use the same computer and session and login to a different LinkedIn account.

- Is this possible?
- If not? Is there a way to delete the LinkedIn cookies? so that the user's LinkedIn session is finished and by being logged out from LinkedIn then they will have to grant access to my application again.

For reference:

- I'm using Grails 2.1.1
- I'm **NOT** using oauth to do the authentication, I just use the HTTPClient from Groovy to do plain and simple GET and POST requests.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: found old article from linkedin with `Invalidation` API . but it out of date and not work anymore
https://blog.linkedin.com/2010/04/29/linkedin-platform-oauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just to delete the Access Token from your storage. This way you no longer have access to that account. When LinkedIn was using OAuth 1.0a, they had an Invalidate call which would invalidate the Access Token. But when they moved to OAuth 2.0, that went away.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the fast answer. If I delete the access token it's the same as doing the refresh flow again because LinkedIn realizes that the user is still logged in to the site and that the current token is still valid so it returns a new Access Token valid for 60 more days without asking me to authenticate again. That's specifically the problem I'm having.

Comment: There really isn't a way to remotely log a user out of LinkedIn. So, using the same session makes this almost impossible to do.

Comment: Hi @JuanVidal, did you figure out how to resolve this ?

Comment: HI Nihad, I didn't actually. As Mark mentioned the invalidate method is no longer available. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to revoke token on API v2 with this call:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/revoke \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE \
  --data client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_HERE \
  --data token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
```